# Migrating a database with modifiable primary keys to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, migration, firebird

I have to migrate a Firebird database to MS SQL, and the original author designed the database in the way that it has mutable primary keys. For example, we have a tables

```
PRODUCTS with primary key (NAME,CATEGORY,SHORTNAME) and some data
PRICE_LISTING (NAME,CATEGORY,SHORTNAME) - foreign key to PRODUCT, and some data like price
PRODUCT_ALTERNATIVES (ORIGINAL_NAME,ORIGINAL_CATEGORY,ORIGINAL_SHORTNAME; REPLACEMENT_NAME,REPLACEMENT_CATEGORY,REPLACEMENT_SHORTNAME) - foreign keys to PRODUCTS
```

as you can see, whenever product name changes, lot of data in other tables has to change. The original author solved this with cascading update on the foreign keys. For some reasons, MS SQL doesn't allow me to use cascading update on the foreign key, so the database cannot be migrated so easily.

What makes things worse is that the software has a lot of editing screens, that use DataSets, DataGridViews and binding in Windows Forms, so the editor works pretty much automagically. For example, editor for `PRODUCTS` is a simple windows form, and whenever user renames a product (changes its `NAME`), the changes are propagated through database (via cascading update) to `PRICE_LISTING` and `PRODUCT_ALTERNATIVES` tables. And also, if the app wants to show price listings, it does simple `SELECT * FROM PRICE_LISTING` that includes product names and price.

One approach might be to add surrogate keys - `ID` identity columns to each table, then modify for example `PRICE_LISTING` table to (`PRODUCT_ID, price`) etc. But then, to show price, I'd have to define view that will

```
SELECT *,PRODUCT.NAME,PRODUCT.CATEGORY,PRODUCT.SHORTNAME FROM PRICE_LISTING join PRODUCT on ...
```

then, the automatically generated DataSets etc. will have to be modified to select from view, update the view.

In a nutshell and from the original author's perspective, we are breaking the program and making it more complicated. The only single thing that does not work when ported in a straightforward manner is the cascading update, but I see that the database design is very flawed and it will be a maintenance nightmare if not fixed.

What to do?

Comment: throw it away and do it properly?

Comment: Have you actually tried `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, because SQL Server does support it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Surely, and Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__STUFF__019E3B86' on table 'STUFF' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
It happens when I attempt to create multiple cascade paths, which the original DB design contains
||
MSDN states: No table can appear more than one time in the list of all cascading referential actions that result from the DELETE or UPDATE.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. A potential solution might be to create a better structure, and then provide views to support the legacy application. Updates and inserts through those views might 'just' work (depending on the exact view definition), or you could provide triggers to do updating of dependent tables (if necessary).